# Using an ImageReader with an OutputConfiguration, so I can use physicalIds

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

So I've been able to modify the camera2Video sample to use physical Camera Ids by using createCaptureSessionByOutputConfiguration. For the preview I've done

```
if(currentLens.isPartOfLogicalCam){
    OutputConfiguration outputconfig = new OutputConfiguration(previewSurface);
    outputconfig.setPhysicalCameraId(currentLens.getPhysicalCameraId());

    mCameraDevice.createCaptureSessionByOutputConfigurations(Collections.singletonList(outputconfig),
            new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {...}
```

and in  startRecordingVideo()

```
if(currentLens.isPartOfLogicalCam){
    List<OutputConfiguration> outputconfigs = new ArrayList<>();
    outputconfigs.add(new OutputConfiguration(previewSurface));
    outputconfigs.add(new OutputConfiguration(recorderSurface));
    outputconfigs.get(0).setPhysicalCameraId(currentLens.getPhysicalCameraId());
    outputconfigs.get(1).setPhysicalCameraId(currentLens.getPhysicalCameraId()); 

    mCameraDevice.createCaptureSessionByOutputConfigurations(outputconfigs, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {...}
```

This works; both the preview and the recorded video use the desired physical camera id.

Now I want to make the analogous modifications to the Camera2Raw sample, so that I can use the physical Ids to take DNG images.

In the `createCameraPreviewSessionLocked()` function, I've changed it to use `.createCaptureSessionByOutputConfigurations`, like

```
OutputConfiguration surfaceOutputConfig = new OutputConfiguration(surface);
OutputConfiguration rawImageOutputConfig = new OutputConfiguration(mRawImageReader.get().getSurface());
List<OutputConfiguration> outputConfigs = Arrays.asList(surfaceOutputConfig, rawImageOutputConfig);
outputConfigs.get(0).setPhysicalCameraId("4");
outputConfigs.get(1).setPhysicalCameraId("4");

ArrayList<Surface> surfaces = new ArrayList<>();
surfaces.add(surface);
surfaces.add(mRawImageReader.get().getSurface());

mCameraDevice.createCaptureSessionByOutputConfigurations(outputConfigs,
        new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
...
```

I've also temporarily hardcoded the imageReader resolution to be 4000x3000, because I know the underlying sensor I'm trying to access has that as its max resolution. The preview shows the correct lens, but when I try to take a picture, the app crashes and I get "Height and width of image buffer did not match height and width of either the preCorrectionActiveArraySize or the pixelArraySize."

**Update:** for the heck of it, I tried instantiating the Image Reader to use JPEG instead of RAW. And what do you know, now it works! When I use the telephoto lens for instance, I get JPEGs at the correct 4000x3000 size, and they are clearly taken by the correct lens.

So I've gotten this logic working for video and JPEG images. Why not RAW? I guess it has something to do with the preCorrectionActiveArraySize or pixelArraySize. Is there any way I can set those things directly?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out, and I think the key was making sure the current `CameraCharacteristics` is based on the current physical ID. I now make sure to set it explicitly in my lens-changing code. (Apparently doing this isn't necessary for taking JPEGs.)

Note however that `openCamera` can only be called on a Logical/non-physical ID, so I use the corresponding logical ID of the current physical when I call that function.